# .htaccess redirect all requests to perl file

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect all requests to a perl file which is supposed to handle them depending on the sub domain.

I tried using this .htaccess:

```
Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler fcgid-script .pl
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+?)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/main.pl/$1 [L]
```

I would expect that, if I try to open master.example.com that my ~/html-root/master/main.pl would get executed, but instead I get an "Internal Server Error".

Apache's error_log says

```
[Wed Jan 20 18:06:36 2016] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: http://master.example.com/
```

If I try to visit example.com/master/main.pl my script gets executed just fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found sort of a workaround:

```
Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler fcgid-script .pl
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_ENV} !^.+$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+?)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/main.pl/$1 [L,E=ENV:%1]
```

Instead of not redirecting requests to `/\1/main.pl` I set an environment variable on the first redirect. If that variable is set, I don't do any more redirects thus getting out of the infinite loop that otherwise would be happening.

Answer (score 1):

Try your rule this way,

```
Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler fcgid-script .pl
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+?)\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %1::%{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*?)::/\1/? [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/main.pl/$1 [L]
```

Comment: This works. Could you please explain to me what your line does?

Comment: @dave The problem is you need to make sure you ignore the subfolder your are pointing to. In your case it's `dynamic` because it depends on the subdomain. You can't use backreference in the regex of the rewritecond. So this rule uses the backrefence `%1` on the left side string by matching and grouping the block of text before :: and compare using the `\1` reference. It's basically the static equivalent of `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/master [NC]`

Comment: master.example.com/master throws an error, again. This time it says Forbidden …

Comment: _Probably_ because you don't have an index file in that directory. Indexing is turned off so you should get a forbidden. Add a index file `index.html`, `index.php` etc.

Comment: It should just redirect to my `~/html-root/master/main.pl` and append the requested URL to it. I did that by changing your line to `RewriteCond %1::%{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*?)::/\1/main.pl` which fixes that but now `master.example.com/master/main.pl` doesn't get called as `example.com/master/main.pl/master/main.pl` would.

Comment: The original issue is solved and would be better to ask another. Can you put your new problem in a new question and I'll try and help you with that?

Comment: The original issue was "I want to redirect all requests to a perl file" which isn't actually resolved.

Comment: It was. Actually your question doesn't say you want to access `master.example.com/master/main.pl` it shows `master.example.com` which is how your **original** rule was setup for. But because you weren't ignoring the subfolder it was causing a redirect loop which was solved. Now that you are adding another condition,  why would you want to access `master.example.com/master/main.pl` directly? That doesn't seem to make sense based on your original question. And isn't not nice or customary to change your requirement after the **original error** is now gone.

Comment: I don't _want_ to access `master.example.com/master/main.pl` directly. But that's what it does. I want _all_ requests to be handled by `~/html-root/%1/main.pl`, where %1 is the sub domain. I don't see how my question has changed?

Comment: That's currently what the rule should be doing. You said it worked. If you go specifically to `master.example.com` does it not execute your script? Or what does it do?

Comment: My script currently only prints the requested path. If I visit `master.example.com` it prints `/`, if I visit `master.example.com/foobar` it prints `/foobar`. That is what I want. But if I visit `master.example.com/master/main.pl` it prints `/` instead of `/master/main.pl`.

Comment: That's what Im saying, The rule should not be executing if you navigate to `master.example.com/master/main.pl` That was the point of why I added the RewriteCond, if you don't have that there it will cause a redirect loop, which is the 500 error you got before because you are calling the same file you are internally redirecting to. So are you sure it's not your script?